# Find files in a directory and zip them into one location in same location using shell script

Tags: file, shell, zip, creation

I have written a properties file as follows:

### appl.properties

```
directory=/tmp/samplescript

ZipFileName=FileN

Namese=Text1.doc Text2.doc
```

---

### I have my shell script as follows:

```
# source the properties:  
. appl.properties  

# Then reference then:  
echo $directory

#find ${directory}  zip -r ${ZipFileName} ${Namese} {}\;
#find $directory zip $ZipFileName $Namese {}\;

find $directory -type -f -execdir zip -j $ZipFileName {}\;

#zip -r ${directory} ${ZipFileName}
```

---

I want to find the directory that i mentioned and the names of the files that are mentioned and zip with the file i have specified into the same directory/Different directory

Comment: The proper parameter is `-type f`, not `-type -f`.

Comment: THis is my Shell Script which i used and i have the file names seperated the ; as the delimiter in the properties file: But Still Not Working.Please correct the one that you mentioned:----------------------------    # source the properties:  
    . appl.properties  
       
    # Then reference then:  
    echo $directory
 
 find $directory -execdir for x in $Namese ; do zip -j -a $ZipFileName {} ; done \;

Comment: I removed my prior suggestion because the `execdir` didn't like using the shell loop construct for some reason. It declared that `do` wasn't a valid token.

Comment: Ok, the test with -type f is also not working as expected..

Comment: It's a necessary fix nonetheless. But your `find` still doesn't use `$Namese` so it's not going to only pick those file names. Is that what you mean by "not working as expected"?

Comment: Correct: My intention is to pick the file names mentioned , directory and the .zip file name from the properties and create a zip file with all the file names mentioned

Comment: OK, I have an updated answer for you to check out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want to zip files that match names in `$Namese`. In your script, try replacing the `find` command with:

```
export Namese

find $directory -type f -exec sh -c '[[ $Namese =~ (^| )`basename "$0"`($| ) ]] && zip -j -a `dirname $0`/$ZipFileName `basename $0`' {} \;
```

The `sh` in the `-exec` will run `zip` if the file name is in the listed `$Namese`.

This will look in each subdirectory of `$directory`, and if any files are found there that have names in the list `$Namese`, it will put them into a zip file in that same directory and name the zip file `$ZipFileName`. I believe that's what the question was asking for.

Comment: Getting this exception while i run:find: invalid argument `-f' to `-type'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: SHELL SCRIPT USED:    # source the properties:  
    . appl.properties  
       
    # Then reference then:  
    echo $directory
 
 find $directory -execdir for x in $Namese ; do zip -j -a $ZipFileName {} ; done \;

Comment: @user2846995 That's what I had originally commented on. The proper parameter is `-type f`, not `-type -f`.

Comment: We are facing : 
find: missing argument to `-exec'
error while we run the above provided script.

Comment: @user2846995 Did you enter it exactly as shown? I tested it several times and it worked for me. That error sometimes mean that the trailing ` \;` is missing or doesn't have the space. Or there may be another character missing confusing he parse. Also, I just added that you need to `export Namese` for subshells to see it.